# How do you find the inverse of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was messing around and reviewing for my math final by creating my own functions which I was going to be finding the inverse of, and I just randomly created this function:

$$f(x)=\frac {x^2+3}{x-1}$$
and I got stuck at
$$y^2+3=x(y-1)$$
and I have no clue how to continue further. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how so solve quadratic equations?

Comment: This is not a 1-1 function,  so why should have an inverse?

Answer (score 1):

$$y^2+3=x(y-1)$$

HINT

$$y^2-y\; x + (x+3) $$

is a quadratic equn you can solve in the usual way.

$$ y=\frac{x\pm \sqrt{....}}{2} $$

When graphed there can be found two parts separated by an asymptote

$$y=1 .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)$. Then by definition, $x=f^{-1}(y)$. So, you need to express $x$ as a function of $y$ to get the desired inverse function. By setting $y=f(x)$, we have
$$ xy-y=x^2+3 \implies x^2 -(y-1)x+3=0. $$ The solution to this quadratic equation is $f^{-1}(y)$. Now, can you solve that quadratic equation?
$$ f^{-1}(y)=\frac{-(-(y-1))\pm \sqrt{\dots}}{2} .$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2+3 = x(y-1)$$
$$\implies y^2 -xy+(x+3) = 0$$
Using the quadratic formula yields the solution(s) to this equation:
$$f_i(x) := \frac{x\pm \sqrt{x^2 -4(x+3)}}{2},$$
where $i=1,2$ corresponds to plus and minus respectively (provided the discriminant is nonzero).

---

Recalling $f(x) = \frac{x^2+3}{x-1}$, we want to show:
$$f_i\circ f = Id_{dom(f)}\text{ and }f\circ f_i = Id_{dom(f_i)},$$
which would define $f_i$ as two sided inverse(s) to $f$ as desired.

---

Accordingly, let us try the first equation:
$$f_i\circ f (x) = \frac{f(x)\pm\sqrt{f(x)^2-4(f(x)+3)}}{2}$$
$$f_i\circ f (x) = \frac{\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+3)^2}{(x-1)^2}-4(\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}+3)}}{2}$$
Combining the fractions in the radical:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+3)^2 - 4(x^2+3)(x-1) -12(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^2}}\bigg]$$
Simplifying:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^4+6x^2+9 - 4(x^3-x^2+3x-3) -12(x^2-2x+1)}{(x-1)^2}}\bigg]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^4+6x^2+9 - 4x^3+4x^2-12x+12 -12x^2+24x-12}{(x-1)^2}}\bigg]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x+9}{(x-1)^2}}\bigg]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)^2(x-3)^2}{(x-1)^2}}\bigg].$$
*(Graphical analysis was used to determine the factorization. If you graph the numerator, the roots at -1 and 3 are blatant and the graph doesn't cross so the multiplicities are even, suggesting the result of the last step.)*
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}\pm \frac{(x+1)(x-3)}{x-1}\bigg]$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{x^2+3\pm (x^2-2x-3)}{x-1}\bigg]$$
Now in the positive case:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{2x(x-1)}{x-1}\bigg] = x = Id_{dom(f)}.$$
But in the negative case:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{2(x+3)}{x-1}\bigg] = \frac{x+3}{x-1} \neq x.$$

---

So $f_1$ is at least a left-inverse of $f$.  
I'll leave the other side verification to you! Not sure why $f_2$ failed theoretically... Look into the discriminant assumption!